# How to use grep, cut with ' and " in groovy script?

Tags: bash, groovy, grep, jenkins-pipeline

In shell scripting, I want to run the following command from a groovy script. `${location}` `${PRODUCT}` `${VERSION}` are parameters that are provided in the groovy script.

```
filename=$(ls ${location} | grep -e "${PRODUCT}-${VERSION}.*full.zip" | cut -d'+' -f2 | cut-d'.' -f1)
```

So I tried the .execute() command like below.

```
def filename = (ls ${location} | grep -e "${PRODUCT}-${VERSION}.*full.zip" | cut -d'+' -f2 | cut-d'.' -f1).execute()
```

But the expected result didn't come. Please help me to run this command from a groovy file.

Comment: The command should be a string. Use quotation instead of brackets

Comment: @UladzislauKaminski I tried that too. But it didn't work. The reason is I have another quotation mark used in grep command.

Comment: Be aware that you can use single quotation mark inside GString (string with double quotation mark). @JanethFernando

Comment: Thank you @UladzislauKaminski I removed double quotation marks. Also, I had to the following line and run the execute method to that. Then it worked.

['bash', '-c', filename].execute()